# How can I add JSON items to a PHP string?

Tags: php

I'm trying to concatenate some JSON items into a string in PHP. This is my JSON list:

```
{
   "StatusCode":200,
   "UserAccess":"True",
   "Username":"James"
}
```

I want to concatenate items from my JSON list to a string. This is what I tried to do:

```
echo "Your username is $jsonItems['Username']"
```

This returned an error stating:
`syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in file`

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Yup that's what I was doing. (Made a mistake when I wrote it again in SO, sorry about that.)

Comment: Three possible problems: One, use `.` to concat if you also need to index. Secondly, JSON is a string so you can't key into it -- have you parsed this into an array already? Thirdly, you may have decoded the JSON into an object rather than an array, which means you need to use `->` to access the property rather than brackets. Please show a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: `json_decode` converts it back to a php object.

Comment: You can use `json_decode` to convert json to php objects and then access them as normal.

Comment: Any reason you unselected my answer?

Comment: @JordanCasey oh sorry about that! Must've been an accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value that you're accessing is an object. This is seen by the curly braces. You can concatenate the string as seen below.

`echo "Your username is " . $jsonItems->Username`

Answer (score 1):

> This is my JSON list:

But you omitted to explain how you imported the data into PHP. With json_decode() there are two possibilities:

```
$jsonItems=json_decode($json_string, true); // as an associative array
echo "Your username is $jsonItems[Username]"; 
// note the index is unquoted when embedded in a string
```

but if you imported it as a PHP object then you'd need to use tring concatenation...

```
$jsonItems=json_decode($json_string); // as an object
echo "Your username is" . $jsonItems->Username;
```